# Unable to display option selected through a spinner

Tags: java, android

I want the option selected in the spinner menu to be displayed in a textview whose id is 'spinnertxt'.

I'm able to open the spinner menu and select the option, but after that nothing happens.

Here is the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class Addproject extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

protected int mPos;
protected String mSelection;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_addproject);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.difficultyspinner); ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> 
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.difficultyarray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_addproject, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Addproject.this.mPos = pos;
    Addproject.this.mSelection = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

    TextView spinnerresult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spinnertxt);
    spinnerresult.setText(Addproject.this.mSelection);

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //NOTHING TO LOOK HERE, MOVE ALONG

}

  }
```

Can someone tell me why? I'm new to this.

Comment: try using adapter.getItem(pos)  instead of parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

Comment: @G_S what is 'adapter' over here? It's asking me to declare it as a variable.

Comment: that's your Arrayadapter object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

A listener was missing.

I just added

> ```
> spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
> ```

to `onCreate()` after `setAdapater()`

The listener is needed so that the application listens for taps on particular items.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate your array and use

```
Addproject.this.mSelection = array[pos];
```

instead of

```
Addproject.this.mSelection = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
```

Comment: Nope! Not working.
I made the array initialize as null. Is that okay?